# belongs_to with different foreign key as well as primary key in the other table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

I have two models:

`Ticket` and `User`

A ticket belongs_to a User, and a User has_many Tickets.

The thing here is that I want to associate these two models with:

The ticket has a `ref_token` column and the User has a `token` column.  So, basically when trying to find the User for a given token (token123), I would expect the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM tickets WHERE token = 'token123'
```

How can I set the association to accomplish this (basically I want to specify the columns that set the association. In this case they are different than the primary keys).

I have this now:

```
User

has_many :tickets, foreign_key: 'ref_token', primary_key: 'token'

Ticket

belongs_to :user, foreign_key: 'ref_token', primary_key: 'token'
```

And I am able to do `user.tickets`, but I can't do `ticket.user`. It keeps returning `nil`.

Comment: Why you want to use token column for `token.user` it can be handled just with `has_many :tickets, foreign_key: 'ref_token'`

Comment: Look in your log - what sql is being executed in the non-working attempt?

Answer (score 3):

I guess it should be:

```
has_many :tickets, foreign_key: "ref_token"

belongs_to :user, foreign_key: "token"
```